# Find Duplicates from columns in CSV and Remove before write

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, duplicates, export-to-csv

I'm creating a csv file from reading multiple text file i have created as below

```
Col1,  Col2,  Col3,  Col4
name1, copy, create, copy
       cut           paste

name2, data, null , data
       cut           cut
```

i want to remove duplicates from **column4** comparing with **column2** before writing to csv. like above from **row1**, **column4** should only be **paste** like wise in **row2**, **column4** should be **empty**

desired output be like:

```
Col1,  Col2,  Col3,  Col4
name1, copy, create, paste
       cut           

name2, data, null , 
       cut
```

i have something like below

```
stat2 = 'Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4\n'
text_file=os.listdir('.data/')
for pack in text_file:
    file = open("./data/"+ pack, "r")
    perp = file.read()
stat2 += pack + ',"'

#I'm iterating through different set of list and matching with all multiple files.
for word in package:
    stat2 += word + "\n"
stat2 += '","'

for word in data:
    stat2 += word + "\n"
stat2 += '","'

for word in file:
    stat2 += word + "\n"
stat2 += '"' + "\n"

f = open("data/csv_file.csv", "w")
f.write(stat2)
```

I want to remove duplicates before writing it to csv. Can anyone please suggest any update on this. Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what is going on with the line breaks in the desired output. Is the second value in column 2 really on a separate line?

Comment: i'm just comparing with text files with list and adding into columns.

Comment: can you represent the input as it appears in the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question is not very clear. however what you can generally do is compare and edit the elements of one list with another list and remove the duplicates from the target list. suppose in this instance, col2 is the target list:

```
col1 = ['copy','create','cut']
col2 = ['copy','create','cut','delete']
```

you can use a list comprehension to create a new list that has only the unique values:

```
col2 = [i for i in col2 if i not in col1 ]
```

and then if you print the result, you'll get this for col2:

`['delete']`